# GridView loading images again when onclick again

Tags: android, image, gridview, onclick

My problem is simple: when I click on the icon to show the GridView, it shows me grid of photos, then I back again and again I click on icon to see GridView and it's showing 2 grids with the same photos. For example if at first I had photo 1, photo 2 I press again and it shows photo 1, photo 2, photo 1, photo 2. I thought I could solve it by adding SharedPreferences (to check if user is in GridView for the first time). Is there any better, easier way to solve my problem? GridView's code:

```
public static List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

...

```
items.add(new Item("Name1", "Text1", R.drawable.pic_12));
        items.add(new Item("Name2", "Text2", R.drawable.pic_13));
        items.add(new Item("Name3", "Text3", R.drawable.pic_14));
        items.add(new Item("Name4", "Text4", R.drawable.pic_15));
        items.add(new Item("Name5", "Text5", R.drawable.pic_2));

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, items));
```

ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return items.get(i).drawable;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;

        if (v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.squareimageview, viewGroup, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
            v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
        }

        picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.text);

        Item item = (Item) items.get(i);

        picture.setImageResource(item.getDrawable());
        name.setText(item.name);

        return v;
    }

}
```

Item class:

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    int drawable;
    String text;

    public int getDrawable() {
        return drawable;
    }

    public void setDrawable(int drawable) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    public Item(String name, String text, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.text = text;
        this.drawable = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i've told you on your previous question, don't use static modifier for your list. Change this:

```
public static List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

for this:

```
public List<Item> items;
```

If you go with static array of data, the data will persist until you close your application, because it is class dependant (not instance).

Then, change this in your code:

```
items = new ArrayList<Item>();

items.add(new Item("Name1", "Text1", R.drawable.pic_12));
    items.add(new Item("Name2", "Text2", R.drawable.pic_13));
    items.add(new Item("Name3", "Text3", R.drawable.pic_14));
    items.add(new Item("Name4", "Text4", R.drawable.pic_15));
    items.add(new Item("Name5", "Text5", R.drawable.pic_2));

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, items));
```